# Python requests NTLM without password

Tags: python, python-requests, ntlm

I am trying to access a website that uses NTLM authentication. I have been successfully able to retrieve the content using the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library in combination with [requests-ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm). However to use that I have to provide both username and password in the code or as an input from the user.

If I access the same site in any of my browsers I am not asked for anything, it just works. How can I avoid the need to enter the password using python ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is : Do you need to avoid entering passwords on the shell ? or during the request you want to "fill the form" automatically ? Do you need to avoid storing the password in hardcoded version ?

Comment: I would want to avoid any password in the code or from the shell. Since the OS (using Chrome, Vivaldi, IE) is able to access the site without any input I assume that should in theory be possible from python too; I am just not sure how.

Comment: Maybe the user authentication has been recorded by the website in a browser cookie - have you tried clearing all browser cookies and then accessing the website? A brief search for: _authentication ntlm browser_ turns up this: http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/ describing in fact how browser config can make it automatically authenticate with your Windows username/password.

Comment: @barny right so maybe Firefox does need some tweaking, I didn't try it. But the ones I tried worked also after clearing all data. But what you linked to hints that the browser autologin is called ntlm sso then.

Comment: I strongly suspect the simplest solution might be to implement your app within your browser, e.g. in javascript/websockets(?).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54343596/851737